# How to print the variable and use it from the if sentence in windbg script?

Tags: windbg

1,For how to print the variable, I used the following sentence with windbg script, however it fail to print it.

```
 r @$t0 = 123;
   .printf  @$t0
```

2,How to use the variable in if sentence, however I still found it failed.

```
 r @$t0 = 123;
 .if(@$t0 ==123)
{
.printf  @$t0
}
```

How to modify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your way to use pseudo-register isn't wrong, but:

1) .printf() takes a format string as it does in C

2) By default, numbers are in Hex rather than decimals, use 0n or 0x to mention their base explicitly

3) Historically you shouldn't have used '@' to set a pseudo register with 'r', although I believe now it works in either way

```
r $t0 = 0n123;
.if ( @$t0 == 0n123 )
{ 
 .printf "%d", @$t0 
}
```

Comment: I could not 100% follow the number base issue. If he assigns in hex and then checks in hex, there should not be a problem, right?

Comment: Right Thomas, I just wanted to point to Jason that the tests of his real-world scripts might not behave correctly if he compares numbers against different bases. The sample script he shows, assigning a value and testing it directly won't face such number base issue.

Answer (score 1):

**$$ sum of triangular numbers in windbg script**

```
r eax=0;r $t0=0;.while(@$t0<10){r eax=@eax+@$t0;.printf "%2d=%3d\n",@$t0,@eax;r $t0=@$t0+1}
```

result

```
 0=  0
 1=  1
 2=  3
 3=  6
 4= 10
 5= 15
 6= 21
 7= 28
 8= 36
 9= 45
10= 55
11= 66
12= 78
13= 91
14=105
15=120
```

lets confirm `f(n) = n * (n+1) /2`

```
 ? 0n15 * (0n16/2)
Evaluate expression: 120 = 00000078
```